# bazel 7 fails to find header files

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp

I am new to bazel and am playing around with monorepo and multirepo builds with dependencies.

I successfully setup the [monorepo](https://bitbucket.org/szarmach/mono/src/main/) but am unable to get the multrepo to work.

For the multirepo I created two C++ repositories where repo [app2](https://bitbucket.org/szarmach/app2/src/main/) depends on repo [lib2](https://bitbucket.org/szarmach/lib2/src/main/)
When I build app2  I would like bazel to fetch lib2. To achieve this I have added a git_repository definition to my WORKSPACE.
My issue is that when I run bazel build //app2:app bazel complains that it can not find the lib2 headers

```
INFO: Analyzed target //app2:app2 (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
ERROR: /home/bazel/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bazel/36a4e7d3b3c11620f7fa4375ad21cf55/external/lib2/BUILD.bazel:6:11: Compiling time_util.cpp failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target @@lib2//:time_util) /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++11' -MD -MF ... (remaining 21 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
external/lib2/time_util.cpp:1:10: fatal error: lib2/time_util.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "lib2/time_util.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ERROR: /home/bazel/testing/app2/BUILD.bazel:7:10: Compiling app2/app.cpp failed: (Exit 1): gcc failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target //app2:app2) /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++11' -MD -MF ... (remaining 32 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
app2/app.cpp:1:10: fatal error: lib2/time_util.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "lib2/time_util.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My bazel files are as follows

WORKSPACE.bazel

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
    name = "lib2",
    remote = "https://wszarmach@bitbucket.org/szarmach/lib2.git",
    branch = "main", # branch, tag, commit, hash
)
```

app2/BUILD.bazel

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["app.cpp"],
    #deps = ["//lib2:time_util"],
    deps = ["@lib2//:time_util"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

lib2/BUILD.bazel

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

cc_library(
    name = "time_util",
    srcs = ["time_util.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["time_util.h"],
    #hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
    copts = ["-Ilib1"],
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Searching stack overflow I have seen various solutions to almost identical issues but I have not been able to apply them successfully.

What am I missing for the multi repo case to have bazel build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a single `WORKSPACE.bazel` file, which means you would have a single repository — to have two repos, you'd need two `WORKSPACE.bazel` files. If I clone both of your repos (`app2` and `lib2`), and I put the `WORKSPACE.bazel` file you mentioned in the root, and run a `bazel query //...`, I get the two targets:

```
//app2:app
//lib2:time_util
```

As a side note, since you're using Bazel 7, you might want to switch to using `MODULE.bazel` instead of `WORKSPACE.bazel` files. So here is how you'd do something like this with Bazel modules, which is the *modern* way of managing dependencies.

Create a file `app2/MODULE.bazel`:

```
bazel_dep(name = "rules_cc", version = "0.0.9")

non_module_dependencies = use_extension("//:extensions.bzl", "non_module_dependencies")
use_repo(non_module_dependencies, "lib2")
```

Then create the `app2/extensions.bzl` file:

```
"""Registers any non-module dependencies here."""

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

def _non_module_dependencies_impl(_ctx):
  git_repository(
      name = "lib2",
      remote = "https://wszarmach@bitbucket.org/szarmach/lib2.git",
      branch = "main", # branch, tag, commit, hash
  )

non_module_dependencies = module_extension(
    implementation = _non_module_dependencies_impl,
)
```

The `name = lib2` in the `git_repository` arg is what you need to add in the `use_repo` call in `MODULE.bazel`, to make it available as a module dependency.

You also need `rules_cc`, which comes straight from the [BCR](https://registry.bazel.build/).

Now that you have your dependencies set up, you need to change your `app2/BUILD.bazel` as follows:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
  name = "app",
  srcs = ["app.cpp"],
  deps = ["@lib2//:time_util"]
)
```

Note that now we're using `@lib2//:time_util` instead of `//lib2:time_util`.

You no longer need the `WORKSPACE.bazel` file in the root directory, since you don't have a package root there. Each repo has its own package root.

After setting this all up, you'll notice that the build will still fail. This is because in `app.cpp`, you reference the library like this:

```cc
#include "lib2/time_util.h"
```

You need to change this to be:

```cc
#include "time_util.h"
```

This is because, while previously you needed the full paths from the workspace root, now each workspace has its own root, and in `lib2`, `time_util.h` is actually at the root, not under a sub-package.

When you invoke `bazel build //:app` and it fails, you can see that Bazel adds the C compiler flag `-iquote external/_main~non_module_dependencies~lib2`, among others. This essentially means anything under the `lib2` repo can be `#include`d using quotes, without any prefix.

Note that, in `lib2`, you also need to change the `#include` in `time_util.cpp`, and don't forget to commit & push the change, or use a local override while developing on multiple modules locally.

Comment: thank you very much your solution works. Two follow up questions if you do not mind
1. if I did want to keep the include as lib2/time_util.h am forced move the cpp & h file to a subdirectory called lib2 or is there another way to do that?
2. I can now build by only cloning out app2 but if I also clone lib2 and make changes to it the build does not detect those changes until I commit them and clear the bazel cache. Is it possible to have bazel first attempt //lib2:time_util and if lib2 is not there switch to @lib2//:time_util?

Comment: 1. I don't know of an easy way to do that (maybe there is, but I'm not familiar with `#include` lookup). 2. Yes, for local development you can use [overrides](https://bazel.build/external/module#overrides), specifically take a look at [`local_path_override`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/globals/module#local_path_override), you need to add it to your `MODULE.bazel` file. Alternatively, you can use [the `--override_module` flag](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--override_module), which you can even add to a `.bazelrc.local` that you `try-import` from your `.bazelrc`.